# Despite installing JDK 8, eclipse reports correct JRE is not being used

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to run this project in Eclipse 2022-03 https://github.com/SERG-Delft/jpacman-framework I have installed JDK 8 but my eclipse is still reporting some issues that it is not detecting the correct JRE. I have also attached the image.

[image]

In the next image, JRE 8 can be seen but I am confused why its reporting such issues.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at compliance level in Java Compiler

Comment: is the JDK-8 added to the Installed JREs (Window - Preferences - Java - Installed JREs)? Also check the Execution Environments.

Comment: Did you configured the Java 8 in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_?